# How to align the ul list in my case?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build an unordered list for my app.

i have something like

html

```
<div id='wrapper' class='container'>
      <ul>
          <li id='first-btn'></li>
          <li id='second-btn'><a href='#'>test</a></li>
          <li id='third-btn'><a href='#'>test 3</a></li>
      </ul>        
  </div>
```

css

```
#wrapper li{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 0;
}

#first-btn{
    background-color: #5A8D17;
}

#second-btn{
    background-color: #80CD1D;
}

#third-btn{
    background-color: #FFEE00;
}
```

However, my end result is so weird.

1. My second and third button are shifted down.
2. I also don't want any gap between li so every button should be close next to each other
   instead of seeing 2px of margin.

http://jsfiddle.net/Mcq6u/

Can anyone help me about this? Thanks a lot

Comment: adding `float:left;` on your li property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You're list items are weirdly aligned because they are vertically-aligned `baseline` by default. The baseline of the text on the right two items are vertically aligned with the baseline of the first (the bottom).

2) The '2px margin' that you see between each is simply a space. Because the list items are displayed `inline-block`, they recognize the white-space.

Change the `vertical-align` and remove/comment the white-space and you have it:

**HTML**

```
<div id='wrapper' class='container'>
    <ul>
        <li id='first-btn'></li><!--
        --><li id='second-btn'><a href='#'>test</a></li><!--
        --><li id='third-btn'><a href='#'>test 3</a></li>
    </ul>        
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mcq6u/5/)

Comment: The only thing that needs to be done is removing the white space in the HTML, if the OP would simply add text to the first button.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change:

```
#wrapper li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    }
```

Also if you need space between them add in the same class:

```
margin: 5px;
```

and adjust pixels according your needs:)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EaMZ5/)

Answer (score 2):

Just change

```
 display: inline-block;
```

to:

```
 float:left;
```

here is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/Mcq6u/2/